# How to remove unrelated elements between 2 sets? Similar to SQL join

Tags: algorithm, join, inner-join

Suppose I have 2 sets like:

```
A = { 1, 4, 7, 10, 11, 12 }
B = { a, b, x, y, z }
```

And I have a function that determines if an element in A is related to another in B:

```
bool isRelated(a, b)
```

I want to remove elements from A and B that don't have any related elements. How can I achieve that? 1 simple way is:

```
forEach a in A:
    related = 0
    forEach b in B:
        if isRelated(a, b):
            related++
            break
    if related == 0 
        A.remove(a)

// then I need to do something similar for B
```

Looks very inefficient to me. Is there a better way? There must be a better way?

Answer (score 0):

this is very simillar in time complexity, but because of the laziness of linq it can save you some of it maybe.

this is a C# example:

```
var newA = A.Where(a=> B.Any(b=> IsRelated(a,b)).Select(a); //checks the desired condition
var newB = B.Where(b=> A.Any(a=> IsRelated(a,b)).Select(b);
A = newA;
B = newB'
```

Comment: fixed the issue you mentioned with A & B types.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a better way in general. SQL databases optimize when they recognize particular conditions in the join clause, for which they can use indexes (either ones that already exist, or data structures built on the fly) to find all matches without scanning the whole set. Not all possible relations have anything to do with any indexes.

You could keep a record in the first loop, of all elements of `B` for which `isRelated` returns true. Then in the not-yet-written second loop, you can check the cache before looping over your (now-reduced) set `A`. Once this is in place, perhaps you could (in the first loop) not always search `B` from the start, so as to give later elements of `B` a better chance of making it into the cache.

Other than that, I don't think there are any big savings on offer here.